# Connecting NodeMCU Lua socket client with node.js socket.io server

Tags: node.js, lua, socket.io, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to connect a NodeMCU Lua socket client to node.js socket.io server.

**NodeMCU Lua code:**

```
sk = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
sk:on("receive", function ( sck,c )
    print (c)
end)

sk:on("connection", function ( sck,c )
    print("Connected")
    sk:send("Helloooo...")
end)
sk:connect(12346,"192.168.1.100")
```

**Node.js server code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('someone is connected');
});
server.listen(12346);
```

**The problem:**

The on connection event in the Lua client is fired and prints "Connected", but the on connection event in node.js socket.io server isn't fired. I tried the Lua client with a Python socket server and it worked well! And I also tried a node.js socket server with a Javascript socket client and it worked well!

Are there compatibility problems between NodeMCU and socket.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Socket.io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO) is a [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) wrapper, not a basic socket implementation. There are some specific operations in it such as handshaking and heartbeat. So you can succeed with socket servers but not with a WebSocket one.

You may use a WebSocket client implementation as well on the [NodeMCU](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/websocket/) side. But I am not sure if the Lua library matches with the WebSocket API version.

If you want async communication, you may use [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT), which has also lots of libraries for NodeJS. Otherwise use the socket server of [NodeJS](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca) as you have done successfully previously.