# Connecting a Lua client to a Socket.io NodeJS server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, lua, socket.io

I have a Node JS server running socket.io able to communicate with other clients using the socket.io-client package. I'm trying to now, write a client in Lua to connect to my socket.io server. Then when it's connected, be able to send and receive events. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to try only with socket IO server then try https://github.com/ignacio/LuaNode-Socket.IO.

Else you have to go with some native websocket implementation.

Also have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379538/connecting-nodemcu-lua-socket-client-with-node-js-socket-io-server)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the LuaSocket module? https://luarocks.org/modules/luarocks/luasocket